# How can I assign an array to a fixed matrix index?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, assign

Don't kill me: I'm a C++ noob.

Here's the [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10be1c4dd8675820):

```
const int lengthA = 3;
const int lengthB = 4;

int main() {
    double matrix[lengthA][lengthB];
    double temp[lengthB];

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthB; i++) {
        temp[i] = i;
    }

    matrix[1] = temp;
}
```

How can I assign an array to a fixed index of a matrix that can contain it? Should I iterate each item on each (sequential) position? I hope I can simple past chunk of memory...

Comment: Small answer, use `std::vector` (You are using C++, not C), big answer use pointers since you cannot assign to an **array**.

Comment: @Ruks - Both of those do not belong in a comment. There is a large text box bellow labeled "answer".

Comment: @StoryTeller That is true! But I already see some answers here! So just let it be...

Comment: @Ruks - If you already see answers you concur with, vote on them. Do not answer in comments. If you wish for me to let it be, do not abuse the comment section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't directly assign *raw* arrays but rather copy their contents or deal with pointers to arrays

```
int main() {
    double* matrix[lengthA]; // Array of pointers, each item may point to another array
    double temp[lengthB]; // Caveat: you should use a different array per each row

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthB; i++) {
        temp[i] = i;
    }

    matrix[1] = temp;
}
```

Keep in mind that this is not a modern C++ way of doing things (where you could be better off using [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector))

Comment: It doesn't see to output correctly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/148ba7e5956e556d

Comment: @markzzz There are several mistakes in that. 1. You are assigning the _same_ pointer to all elements of `matrix` (that pointer is the one to the first element of `temp`, whose adress never changes). 2. `matrix` has only 3 entries - each one is a pointer. You print out the _pointers_ (not any of the contained values), **and** you try to do so for 12 elements of `matrix` while it only has three. Note how the first three output values make sense and the rest don't. The compiler would prevent you from making these mistakes if you used `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: @markzzz you're assigning the same row multiple times. Either assign to the elements of the matrix directly (as in [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/863cd0c8c4eacc47)) or dynamically allocate the rows (e.g. with `new[]`) for the matrix before populating it. Seriously though, give `std::vector` or `std::array` a try unless this is only for didactic purposes.

Comment: I need performance, its high level calculation (audio). Simply using vector increase the CPU :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not, arrays are not assignable.

Here are three possible way to solve it:

- Use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) instead
- Copy the elements from one array to the other (either through [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) or [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy))
- Make `matrix` an array of pointers instead

I recommend `std::array` (or `std::vector`) first, copying second, and using pointers only as a last resort.

Comment: I need performance, its high level calculation (audio). Simply using vector increase the CPU :). It seeems that the faster is memcpy...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `double *matrix[lengthB];` instead of `double matrix[lengthA][lengthB];`